# Zabbix - Value "1" of type "string" is not suitable for value type "Numeric (unsigned)"

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I get this error when I changed the custom command from an application that prints to STDOUT to shell script that runs curl and produces the same output to STDOUT.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the web service that I was calling with curl was responding with UTF-8.

When I changed it to ASCII it all worked out.